# io.popen - how to wait for process to finish in Lua?

Tags: lua, popen

I have to use `io.popen` in Lua to run an executable which takes a command line argument.
How to wait for a process to finish in the Lua so that expected output can be captured?

```
  local command = "C:\Program Files\XYZ.exe /all"

  hOutput = io.popen(command)
  print(string.format(""%s", hOutput))
```

Suppose the executable is XYZ.exe which needs to be called with command line argument `/all`.

Once `io.popen(command)` gets executed, the process will return some string which needs to be printed.

My code snippet:

```
function capture(cmd, raw)
  local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
  -- wait(10000); 
  local s = assert(f:read('*a')) 
  Print(string.format("String: %s",s )) 
  f:close() 
  if raw then return s end 
  s = string.gsub(s, '^%s+', '') 
  s = string.gsub(s, '%s+$', '') 
  s = string.gsub(s, '[\n\r]+', ' ') 
  return s 
end 
local command = capture("C:\Tester.exe /all")
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am having a code somehow it is not working properly

Comment: function capture(cmd, raw)
  local f = assert(io.popen(cmd, 'r'))
 -- wait(10000);  
  local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
 Print(string.format("String: %s",s ))
  f:close()
  if raw then return s end
  s = string.gsub(s, '^%s+', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '%s+$', '')
  s = string.gsub(s, '[\n\r]+', ' ')
  
  return s
end

local command =  capture("C:\Tester.exe /all")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using standard Lua your code looks a bit odd. I am not completely sure about `io.popen` semantics regarding timeouts or platform dependencies, but the following works at least on my machine.

```
local file = assert(io.popen('/bin/ls -la', 'r'))
local output = file:read('*all')
file:close()
print(output) -- > Prints the output of the command.
```

Comment: can you explain, why you need the `assert` around?

Comment: @rubo77, I haven't used Lua in a while, but based on a quick test I don't think the `assert` is at all useful in this case as `io.popen` seems to return an object even when there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with this for capturing relatively big output:

```
io.stdout:setvbuf 'no' 
local file = assert(io.popen('/bin/ls -la', 'r'))
file:flush()  -- > important to prevent receiving partial output
local output = file:read('*all')
file:close()
```