# Shell execute in lua

Tags: powershell, command-line, lua, shellexecute

powershell script

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
##    NEEDED FOR IIS CMDLETS
Import-Module WebAdministration

##    CREATE FTP SITE AND SET C:\inetpub\ftproot AS HOME DIRECTORY
New-WebFtpSite -Name "test" -Port "21" -Force
cmd /c \Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set SITE "test" "-virtualDirectoryDefaults.physicalPath:C:\inetpub\ftproot"

##    SET PERMISSIONS

     ## Allow SSL connections 
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\test" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\test" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy -Value 0

     ## Enable Basic Authentication
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\test" -Name ftpServer.security.authentication.basicAuthentication.enabled -Value $true
## Set USer Isolation
 Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\test" -Name ftpserver.userisolation.mode -Value 3

#Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\test" -Name ftpServer.security.userIsolation. -Value $true

     ## Give Authorization to Administrators and grant "read"/"write" privileges
Add-WebConfiguration "/system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -value @{accessType="Allow";roles="";permissions="Read,Write";users="*"} -PSPath IIS:\ -location "test"
## Give Authorization to All Users 
#appcmd set config %ftpsite% /section:system.ftpserver/security/authorization /+[accessType='Allow',permissions='Read,Write',roles='',users='*'] /commit:apphost 

     ## Restart the FTP site for all changes to take effect
Restart-WebItem "IIS:\Sites\test"
```

that I want to run it with lua

I make that script

```
    function Create_iis()
    tl1="Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
    tl2="Import-Module WebAdministration"
    tl3="New-WebFtpSite -Name \"test\" -Port \"21\" -Force" 
    tl4="cmd \/c \\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd set SITE \"test\" \"-virtualDirectoryDefaults.physicalPath:C:\\inetpub\\ftproot\""
    tl5="Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy -Value 0"
    tl6="Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy -Value 0"
    tl7="Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpServer.security.authentication.basicAuthentication.enabled -Value $true"
    tl8="Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpserver.userisolation.mode -Value 3"
    tl9="Add-WebConfiguration \"\/system.ftpServer\/security\/authorization\" -value \@\{accessType=\"Allow\";roles=\"\";permissions=\"Read\,Write\";users=\"*\"} -PSPath IIS:\ -location \"test\"" 
    tl10="Restart-WebItem \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\""

    file = io.open("c:\\testiis.ps1","w");
    file:write(tl1.."\n"..tl2.."\n"..tl3.."\n"..tl4.."\n"..tl5.."\n"..tl6.."\n"..tl7.."\n"..tl8.."\n"..tl9.."\n"..tl10.."\n"..);
    file:close("c:\\testiis.ps1");
    result = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "open", "c:\\testiis.ps1", "", SW_HIDE,true);
    if result ~=0 then 
        Dialog.Message("Error", "Error ", MB_OK, MB_ICONSTOP, MB_DEFBUTTON1);
    end
end
```

and work well

but I need to check for every line in this script if return error then exit 
and give me the line that make the error

so I make stupid script that

```
    function Create_iis()
result1 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted")
result2 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Import-Module WebAdministration")
result3 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","New-WebFtpSite -Name \"test\" -Port \"21\" -Force" )
result4 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","cmd \/c \\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd set SITE \"test\" \"-virtualDirectoryDefaults.physicalPath:C:\\inetpub\\ftproot\"")
result5 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy -Value 0")
result6 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy -Value 0")
result7 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpServer.security.authentication.basicAuthentication.enabled -Value $true")
result8 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Set-ItemProperty \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\" -Name ftpserver.userisolation.mode -Value 3")
result9 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Add-WebConfiguration \"\/system.ftpServer\/security\/authorization\" -value \@\{accessType=\"Allow\";roles=\"\";permissions=\"Read\,Write\";users=\"*\"} -PSPath IIS:\ -location \"test\"" )
result10 = Shell.Execute("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","open","Restart-WebItem \"IIS:\\Sites\\test\"")

end
```

and check for every result

but there are some commands that depend on each so it make error

it is impossible to make that ?

sorry for poor English

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `Shell.Execute`? I mean where does that function come from?

Comment: it a build in function in setup factory's lua

Comment: What's your purpose for writing a Lua wrapper around an existing, functional PowerShell script?

Comment: I want to implement the powershell command without powershell attached as it contains other things secret

Comment: If I were using just vanilla Lua the solution here would be [`io:popen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) to execute the script and read from its stdout, but I guess that isn't available?

Comment: No, but I do not want this because it would require to attach the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `io.popen` to call a command in Lua:

```
local file = assert(io.popen('/bin/ls -la', 'r'))
local output = file:read('*all')
file:close()
print(output) -- > Prints the output of the command.
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243210/1069083