# Assign bash output to variable in .lua script

Tags: lua

I would like to assign output of a `bash` command to a variable in `.lua` script. Is it possible?

For instance, something similar to:

```
var = `ps uax | grep myprocess`
```

Comment: [A more helpful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5243210/1307154).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`io.popen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) for this.

> io.popen (prog [, mode])
>
> Starts program prog in a separated process and returns a file handle that you can use to read data from this program (if mode is "r", the default) or to write data to this program (if mode is "w").
>
> This function is system dependent and is not available on all platforms.

Also see [How to execute an external command?](http://www.luafaq.org/#T3.2).

> io.popen calls a command but returns a file object so you can read the output of the command, if the second argument is 'r', but you can also pass input to a command with a second argument of 'w'. Unfortunately, you don't get a io.popen2, and you don't get the return code.