# How to return value for a Lua script?

Tags: bash, shell, lua

How can I make my bash return a value for Lua script read function?
If I run script from terminal - output is correct but from lua script I got nil value.

> lua: action.lua:18: attempt to index local 'findKeyInDB' (a nil value)

```
 local findKeyInDB = io.open('sh /home/linux/db.sh 15541993')
 local output = findKeyInDB:read("*a")
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
key=$1
myvariable=$(echo "SELECT id,dkey FROM telegram_keys WHERE dkey="$key"" | mysql -N gamdom_database -u root -ppasswrd)
echo "$myvariable"
```

Comment: you probably meant to use [io.popen](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) instead of io.open.   See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243210/8379597

Comment: @jq170727 yes, you are right!